# Why is CORS-Event-Count" event type is not available for selection in the "Event Log File Browser"

Tags: cors, eventlogfile, event-monitoring

Few users might be receiving emails as "Get Ready to Enforce the CORS Allowlist for Lightning Apps" stating that their org has one or more external domains calling on Salesforce resources that are affected by this change with this KB article linked - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000363113&type=1

Copying text from KB Article:

> Customers should take the following steps to determine impact:
>
> - Log in to your organization. Navigate to the [Event Log File Browser](https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/) application and click Production Login.
> - Set Start Date to today’s date.
> - Select the CORS-Event-Count event type for your search.
> - Choose Interval Value of “Daily.”
> - Click Apply.
> - If the resulting count is 0, then your organization isn’t affected by this release update.
> - If the resulting count is not 0, then your organization is affected by the update. To return the domains that are affected by the update,
>   select the CORS Violation Record and click Apply. This will return the
>   domains that are impacted by the update."

However, CORS-Event-Count event type is not available in the dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//Self-created question to help on the multi customer issue//

This has been reported by several customers. Our Salesforce team is aware of this issue and working on a fix. I will update this thread as I have more details.

**UPDATE(11/Oct/2021)**
The issue has been identified as a documentation bug. The right event type to use would be "CorsViolation" and not "CORS-Event-Count" to determine the impact.The salesforce article will be updated accordingly.